# Read & Parse a JSON file c++ BOOST

Tags: c++, json, boost, boost-propertytree

As there is a lot of questions already on this, I am kind of apprehensive about asking... but

I've looked at many different Questions and nothing from any of them is working for me. I have this code as my attempt but it doesn't work:

```
#include "boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp"
#include "boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp"
using namespace boost::property_tree;
...
std::ifstream jsonFile("test_file.json");
if (!jsonFile){
    std::cerr << "Error opening file\n";
    return -1;
}
ptree pt;
json_parser::read_json(jsonFile, pt);
for (auto& array_element : pt) {
    for (auto& property : array_element.second) {
        std::cout << property.first << " = " << property.second.get_value<std::string>() << "\n";
    }
}
```

Its contents are in the following format:

```
[{"number": 1234,"string": "hello world"}, {"number": 5678,"string": "foo bar"}, ... etc }]
```

I can't get it to read out the `1234` and then the `hello world`. Infact, it just does nothing. How can I read out from my `.JSON` file?

Comment: Do you have an  [ssce](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: Pretty much all of the examples given by @sehe in his **many** answers on this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what the problem is. It seems to work (once you make the JSON valid):

> ### UPDATE: Boost JSON
>
> Boost 1.75.0 introduced Boost JSON, far superior way to actually deal with Json: **[Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/5vEj3l83uwePshNt)**
>
> ```
> #include <boost/json.hpp>
> #include <boost/json/src.hpp>
> #include <iostream>
> #include <iterator>
> #include <fstream>
> namespace json = boost::json;
>
> struct Rec {
>     int64_t number;
>     std::string string;
>
>     friend Rec tag_invoke(json::value_to_tag<Rec>, json::value const& v) {
>         auto& o = v.as_object();
>         return {
>             o.at("number").as_int64(),
>             value_to<std::string>(o.at("string")),
>         };
>     }
>
>     friend void tag_invoke(json::value_from_tag, json::value& v, Rec const& rec)
>     {
>         v = json::object{
>             {"number", rec.number},
>             {"string", rec.string},
>         };
>     }
> };
>
> int main() {
>     std::ifstream ifs("input.txt");
>     std::string   input(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs), {});
>
>     using Recs = std::vector<Rec>;
>     Recs recs  = value_to<std::vector<Rec>>(json::parse(input));
>
>     for (auto& [n, s] : recs) {
>         std::cout << "Rec { " << n << ", " << std::quoted(s) << " }\n";
>
>         // some frivolous changes:
>         n *= 2;
>         reverse(begin(s), end(s));
>     }
>
>     std::cout << "Modified json: " << json::value_from(recs) << "\n";
> }
> ```
>
> Printing
>
> ```
> Rec { 1234, "hello world" }
> Rec { 5678, "foo bar" }
> Modified json: [{"number":2468,"string":"dlrow olleh"},{"number":11356,"string":"rab oof"}]
> ```

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/874a0d2d96f4c651)</kbd>**

```
#include "boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp"
#include "boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp"

int main() {
    using boost::property_tree::ptree;

    std::ifstream jsonFile("input.txt");

    ptree pt;
    read_json(jsonFile, pt);

    for (auto & array_element: pt) {
        for (auto & property: array_element.second) {
            std::cout << property.first << " = " << property.second.get_value < std::string > () << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

With `input.txt` containing:

```
[{"number": 1234, "string": "hello world"},{"number": 5678, "string": "foo bar"}]
```

Prints

```
number = 1234
string = hello world
number = 5678
string = foo bar
```

Comment: does it have to be in `.txt`? my file is currently a `.json`

Comment: Erm. That's just the filename

Comment: I'm clutching at straws here, I didn't think it would be an issue but I gotta ask

Comment: Did you try the example in isolation?

Comment: Re ran it in isolation and it works... odd; I'll just start over, thanks

Comment: Cheers. Fyi, this is exactly what creating [SSCCE's is about](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31251469/read-parse-a-json-file-c-boost/31256188?noredirect=1#comment50500149_31251469). See also [Solve your problem by almost asking on SO](http://blog.jerryorr.com/2014/04/solve-your-problem-by-almost-asking.html)

Comment: can i read json from string. i have my json responses in the string

Comment: @Prince [std::istringstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io#String_I.2FO_implementation)