# Boost stream_translator.hpp build error (C2679)

Tags: c++, boost

I have a program that will create a config file and read from that config file, I already created the structure for that program.

But when I try to build I get this error in "boost/stream_translator.hpp"

[Visual Studio View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNdIm.png)

```cpp
    struct customize_stream
    {
        static void insert(std::basic_ostream<Ch, Traits>& s, const E& e) {
            s << e;
        }
        static void extract(std::basic_istream<Ch, Traits>& s, E& e) {
            s >> e;
            if(!s.eof()) {
                s >> std::ws;
            }
        }
    };
```

```
binary '>>': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'E' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

I'm using VS 2022 Community edition and my Boost version is boost_1_83_0, thanks for any advice.

Comment: Guessing here. The type E needs to have the extraction operator defined. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/overloading-the-input-operator-for-your-own-classes

Comment: Please include relevant code. Your code. Did you follow the documentation on translators for custom types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was going to say "Did you follow the documentation on translators for custom types?" but it turns out there really is none (see also [How do I extend boost property_tree to handle custom types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39100806/how-do-i-extend-boost-property-tree-to-handle-custom-types)).

Also, it would basically only allow you to convert a string value to the entire struct, examples:

- [Boost::property_tree: Using std::vector<> in XML parser to store multiple values in one key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43763816/boostproperty-tree-using-stdvector-in-xml-parser-to-store-multiple-values/43769414#43769414)
- 

In this respect, it could work well if you used something like a JSON representation of the configuration, but then I think that Property Tree adds zero value.

### Using Property Trees

I would write load/save functions myself that operate on `ptree` objects. I have multiple examples of doing that on this site:

- [boost::property_tree : Parsing of Complex xml strucure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47013164/boostproperty-tree-parsing-of-complex-xml-strucure/47019176#47019176)
- [How to use boost c++ property map to extract values from config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43480653/how-to-use-boost-c-property-map-to-extract-values-from-config-file/43483338#43483338)
- [Storing a nested XML structure in form of BGL graph using BOOST library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66314974/storing-a-nested-xml-structure-in-form-of-bgl-graph-using-boost-library/66319940#66319940)
- [Parsing xml using Boost c++ for nested tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48303527/parsing-xml-using-boost-c-for-nested-tags/48308210#48308210)

### Using Boost JSON

Some of the Property Tree examples I've updated to show the superior Boost JSON approach e.g.:

- [Read & Parse a JSON file c++ BOOST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31251469/read-parse-a-json-file-c-boost/31256188#31256188)
- [I can't with C++ boost property_tree parse nested key into JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71978914/i-cant-with-c-boost-property-tree-parse-nested-key-into-json-string/71981241#71981241)

I have a whole host of examples that show how to implement `json::to_value` and `json::from_value` for your type: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a85371%20%20json%20tag_invoke&searchOn=3

Most relevant examples:

- [How create a JSON-file from my data? (with С++, boost json)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73799750/how-create-a-json-file-from-my-data-with-%d0%a1-boost-json/73800788#73800788)